# Area 51 statistics bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange

Apparently Area 51 is bugged. I went to check our questions/day and got this:[image]

Could this reflect something?

Comment: Strange. I was there some hours/a day ago and it did not look like this then. Perhaps it will go away soon.

Comment: At the moment it says 37.7 questions per day!? The avid users still blank. [And we are not the only proposal affected.]

Comment: We wish we had 37.7 questions/day...=(

Comment: Don't be sad! :-) Rome wasn't built in a day. Slowly but steadily we will grow!

Comment: Things seems reasonable again at the moment. Question number is now about 5 per day, which is higher than it used to be, but reasonable if the calculation is done for the full time the site exists or something like this. Might be an intentional change.

Comment: Now it is down to 2.4 again, which is about where we were before the irregularities started. Possibly this means the problem is solved. But then, even a broken clock is right twive a days, so not so clear what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This was a general problem with the software that should be fixed now (thus I tag [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)). I should have thought to check this earlier, it was reported and answered on MSE:

[Who borked the Area 51 stats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234383/who-borked-the-area-51-stats)

(Also on the discussion zone of Area 51, but less details there https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/area-51-stats-down)

Since it was a short and general problem I do not think it reflected in a significant (negative) way on our site.

Thanks for bringing the problem to our attention!